# How can I get the storage usage statistics per user

Tags: 2010, statistics

Is there a way (from Central Admin or using PowerShell) to get the storage used by each user 
I checked Web Analystics and Storage Metrics but found nothing useful

**For Example:**

If I have 10 documents uploaded to a site that is used by 2 users (X and Y)
Can I know how many MBs are uploaded by X and how many MBs are uploaded by Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think so that you will get this kind of statistics OOTB, even if you try to write some piece of code it will not accurate.

- As you Know, SharePoint is the collaboration tool and if i create a document then somebody else make a change to that document, after that another user make a change then under which user you want to calculate this storage. So it is very much complex thing.
- If you want put some restriction on user's storage then you can think about creating a subsite for each user or a Document library for each user, From here you can monitor their storage.
- Other thing is allow the user to create mysite and then set quota on it.

Comment: I don't know how I missed the first point when asked my question :) .. thanks for elaboration @Waqas

Comment: Np, this is common in human like me.